# Convert between String and Regexp

Tags: ruby

I need to convert back and forth between the string representation of a Regexp and the Regexp itself.

Something like this: 
 
`> Regexp.new "\bword\b|other`
`=> /\bword\b|other/`

However, doing so results in `/\x08word\x08|other/`

Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you expecting `\b` to match in the regex?

Comment: I'd like ```\b``` to match a word boundary. e.g. "sword" would not match ```/\bword\b/``` but "word" would.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes so they are treated as characters, as opposed to escaping the following character: `Regexp.new "\\bword\\b|other" #=> /\bword\b|other/`.

Comment: It's probably easier to start with a regex and use `to_s` / `source` to get its string representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes, or escape the backslashes.

```
p re = Regexp.new('\bword\b|other') # => /\bword\b|other/
p re = Regexp.new("\\bword\\b|other")  # => /\bword\b|other/

p re.to_s  # => "(?-mix:\\bword\\b|other)"
p re.inspect # => "/\\bword\\b|other/"
```

The resulting string of `to_s` can be used as argument for `Regexp.new` (as can the regular expression itself).

Comment: Also worth mentioning `%r(#{str})` for interpolated regex.